# how to get a textbox inside a detailsview in a new line?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, detailsview

I want to display the `TextBox` inside a details view in a new line as i am fetching the data from database and trying to make a Form

How do i do this

[image]

**code**

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="520px" 
    AutoGenerateRows="False" GridLines="None">
   <Fields>
   <asp:TemplateField >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDtaLineDtchecked" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DtaLineDtChecked") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDtaLineUsermatch" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DtaLineUserMatch") %>' ></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Fields>
           </asp:DetailsView>
```

Please someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="520px" 
AutoGenerateRows="False" GridLines="None">
    <Fields>
        <asp:TemplateField >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtDtaLineDtchecked" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DtaLineDtChecked") %>' ></asp:TextBox></td>
                        <td><asp:Label ID="lblDtaLineUsermatch" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DtaLineUserMatch") %>' ></asp:Label></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>        
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

** i have put both data inside single templatefield

Comment: works well !! :) but what if i want to put a textbox right below another in this form what code should i use?

Comment: @vini add another row to the table and put the textbox on that row. or you can just add another Templatefield.

Answer (score 1):

You can't

The `DetailsView` control is based on table-views

If you want to implement your custom design you would have to use the `FormView` control and use the correct templates. Example:

```
<asp:FormView runat="server" AllowPaging="true" ID="formView">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%--customize the html--%>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

However consider that the `DetailsView` control automatically creates the design for you, including controls in different modes like Edit, Insert and ReadOnly. When using the `FormView` control, you will have to provide templates for each mode

Comment: so a formview would be better?

Comment: A `FormView` will give you **full control** over the final HTML. At the cost to have to write it manually for each template. Consider the trade-offs for your specific case

Answer (score 0):

Try putting ItemFields in Table Row as follow...

```
   <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="520px"      AutoGenerateRows="False" GridLines="None"> 
       <Fields>
       <table>
             <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:TemplateField >    
                                       <ItemTemplate>   <asp:TextBox ID="txtDtaLineDtchecked" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DtaLineDtChecked") %>' ></asp:TextBox>                 </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
               </td>
                <td>
                   <asp:TemplateField >
                                      <ItemTemplate> <asp:Label ID="lblDtaLineUsermatch" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DtaLineUserMatch") %>' ></asp:Label>                 </ItemTemplate>             
                   </asp:TemplateField>
                </td>
           </tr>
      </table>
      </Fields>
 </asp:DetailsView>
```